# Android - change value of SeekBar within a row (created using ListAdapter)

Tags: android, listview

I've got a `ListView` which is "created" using a custom class that extends `ListAdapter`. I do this by calling

```
listView.setAdapter(new DeviceAdapter...);
```

The `DeviceAdapter` class creates a `ListView` row with a `SeekBar` in it. At runtime I'd to be able to change the value of the `SeekBar`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Ensure that your data model -- whatever it is that you are using to populate your rows in your adapter's `getView()` or `bindView()` -- has the updated data for your `SeekBar`.

Step #2: Iterate over the children of the `ListView` (see methods on `ViewGroup` for this), and if one of them is the row that you want to update, update the `SeekBar`.

Step #3: Ensure that you apply the revised data if the user scrolls and you are now binding data to the row that contains the `SeekBar` you wanted to modify.